# Oracle - Finding the job with most project counts

Tags: sql, oracle, count, max, having

So, I'm quite new to the Oracle and SQL and I encountered a problem with having and max clause - I've been trying to extract the projects with most job names that were working on them, grouping them by job names.
I can acces data just fine, until the having clause, which renders no rows selected query. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
    SELECT PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.JOB, COUNT(EMP.JOB)
FROM EMP, PROJ_EMP
WHERE EMP.EMPNO = PROJ_EMP.EMPNO 
GROUP BY PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.JOB
HAVING COUNT(EMP.JOB) = 
(SELECT MAX(employees) FROM (SELECT COUNT(PROJ_EMP.PROJNO) AS employees FROM
EMP, PROJ_EMP WHERE EMP.EMPNO = PROJ_EMP.EMPNO GROUP BY EMP.JOB))
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Why aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Sample data like tables from my db? Should I just copy it here? Desired result would be render of EMP.JOB i.e "Manager" and PROJ_EMP.PROJNO "6" which would state that most of all employes with EMP.JOB = "Manager" worked on PROJ_EMP.PROJNO "6".

As for why im using simplified syntax for JOIN clause - this is how i was taught, should i consider switching to standard JOIN?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't leave important information in comments. Instead, use the `edit` button just below the tags to edit your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the highest number of job in particular project.

Use **analytical function** as following:

```
SELECT PROJNO,JOB,CNT FROM
(SELECT PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.JOB, 
        COUNT(EMP.JOB) CNT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROJ_EMP.PROJNO ORDER BY COUNT(EMP.JOB) DESC) AS RN
  FROM EMP JOIN PROJ_EMP
    ON EMP.EMPNO = PROJ_EMP.EMPNO 
GROUP BY PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.JOB)
WHERE RN = 1
```

Tip of the day: Always use standard ANSI joins.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This shows that I have much to learn, i will study the analytical functions next, and I wouldn't come up with this myself as of now. Cheers!

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.